# How to set a field named as a value of another field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to transform some document from

```json
{
    "id": 100500,
    "field": {
        "field_name": "some_name"
    }
}
```

to a document like

```json
{
    "id": 100500,
    "field": {
        "some_name": "some_value:
    }
}
```

I've tried to use smth like this `update_one` query:

```json
{
    {"id": 100500},
    {"$set": {"field.$field.field_name": "some_value"}}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic solution would be using `$objectToArray` to convert into array of k-v tuples and use `$map` to do conditional processing. You can preserve potentially other fields in the object in this approach.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "field": {
        "$objectToArray": "$field"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "field": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$field",
          "as": "f",
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $eq: [
                  "$$f.k",
                  "field_name"
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                "k": "$$f.v",
                "v": "some_value"
              },
              "else": "$$f"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "field": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$field"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jUMPf_pJ_qT)